# What is the meaning of strange output after gfortran crash?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm running gfortran on a MAC laptop. My program reached a STOP command after a logical check and terminated as expected. But the stop spawned several empty files with the following names: !,calls,date,file,its,make,so,stamp,that,this,to,tsym,update,and will. 
I've never seen anything like this before. Can anyone explain the meaning of these files?

I tried a GOOGLE search but did not see useful information.

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour]. I do not understand how did it "spawn" the files. Did the names appear on the screen? In that case you have to show us the *exact* output using copy and paste. Or did they appear in your working directory? You should also show your code, best in a form of a [mcve].

Comment: Need a lot more information.  gfortran does not create random files.  Looks more like you redirected the shell's output, and something went left from there.

Comment: The files appeared in the working directory. Unfortunately the code is a few thousand lines long and was modified before I noticed the spawned files.  I have not been able to reproduce the result. That is why it is so strange. It is possible as Steve says that some shell output was redirected and the new files have nothing to do with gfortran. But, it certainly seemed that the files were spawned when the code stopped.  The question was posted to see if anyone has seen this before. If I learn more, I will post a new comment.